# Deploy worker verticle on Virtual Thread

Tags: quarkus, vert.x

How can I deploy the worker verticle on the Virtual Thread. I am planning to deploy some 100000 worker verticles for my use case. The current DeploymentOptions takes setWorkerPoolSize and setWorkerPoolName and doesn't provide a way to provide custom WorkerPool. All my verticles are supposed to run for n minutes after which I undeploy them. If I annotate the consumer method being called on the receipt of the message, that also runs on vertx worker thread

```
@RunOnVirtualThread
public void functionName(final Message<JsonObject> messageConsumer) {
   log.info("function started on {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

I even tried with

```
@ConsumeEvent("test_web_client")
@RunOnVirtualThread
public void consumeTestWebClient(Message<JsonObject> jsonObjectMessage) {   
  log.info("function started on {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for @ConsumeEvent is coming (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/35585).

That being said, I'm not sure that Worker Verticles is the right choice in your case. It might be simpler just to create the virtual threads directly. Note that while possible, creating 100,000 virtual threads has a cost. So, monitor your memory usage and make sure you are not hitting any memory limit.